# ubuntu 16.04 keeps suspending by itself

Tags: 16.04

My device keeps suspending by itself and I am unable to find what is causing it...

Following are the warnings I get from the Xorg.0.log

[    45.714] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.

[    45.714]    Entry deleted from font path.

[    45.715] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.

[    45.715]    Entry deleted from font path.

[    45.715] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.

[    45.715]    Entry deleted from font path.

[    45.715] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.

[    45.715]    Entry deleted from font path.

[    45.715] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.

[    45.715]    Entry deleted from font path.
.
.
.
[    48.250] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting

[    48.250] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
.
.
.

[    48.329] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa

Comment: Which log file should I check to find out what causes my computer to suspend???

Comment: I checked auth.log file and discovered that my laptop is assuming that I closed it's lid.     May  1 21:01:15  systemd-logind[1116]: Lid closed.    May  1 21:01:16 systemd-logind[1116]: Lid opened.  
May  1 21:01:21 systemd-logind[1116]: Lid closed.  
May  1 21:01:22 systemd-logind[1116]: Lid opened. 
May  1 21:01:24 systemd-logind[1116]: Lid closed.  
May  1 21:01:24 systemd-logind[1116]: Lid opened.
May  1 21:01:25 systemd-logind[1116]: Lid closed.  
May  1 21:01:25 systemd-logind[1116]: Lid opened.